# How to send and get multiple response at a time using google real time multiplay service for android?

Tags: android, google-play-services

I am developing an Action based Multi-Player game, like a space shooter. In this game I am facing issues about sending multiple data and receiving multiple data.

For example in a Space shooter game, there are so many resources like, Asteroids, Bullets, Score, Spaceship movement etc,

I want to send, all resources coordinate at a time, and those all movement display on the opponent Screen.

*So how can I send and get multiple response at a time using google's real time multiplay service?*

Comment: Your question is a little broad, I suggest you first take a look at the [docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/realtimeMultiplayer#sending_game_data) and [samples](https://developers.google.com/games/services/downloads/#samples) for Google Play Services.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass all parameter in json object, like if you want shoot bullet, at a time move aircraft to screen and that movement display other side, those all parameter must be pass all time.

ex:
-shoot bullet : pass two parameter 
-movement aircraft : pass two parameter.

Which means we pass all time 4 parameter to perform multiplayer task.